# Get rows where value is not a substring in another row

Tags: sql, recursion, substring

I'm writing recursive sql against a table that contains circular references.
No problem! I read that you can build a unique path to prevent infinite loops. Now I need to filter the list down to only the last record in the chain. I must be doing something wrong though. -edit I'm adding more records to this sample to make it more clear why just selecting the longest record doesn't work.

This is an example table:

```
create table strings (id int, string varchar(200));
insert into strings values (1, '1');
insert into strings values (2, '1,2');
insert into strings values (3, '1,2,3');
insert into strings values (4, '1,2,3,4');
insert into strings values (5, '5');
```

And my query:

```
select * from strings str1 where not exists
(
  select * from strings str2
  where str2.id <> str1.id
  and str1.string || '%' like str2.string
)
```

I'd expect to only get the last records

```
| id |  string |
|----|---------|
|  4 | 1,2,3,4 |
|  5 |       5 |
```

Instead I get them all

```
| id |  string |
|----|---------|
|  1 |       1 |
|  2 |     1,2 |
|  3 |   1,2,3 |
|  4 | 1,2,3,4 |
|  5 |       5 |
```

Link to sql fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7a974/1

Answer (score 0):

My problem was all around the 'LIKE' comparison.

```
select * from  strings str1
where not exists 
(
    select 
      *
    from   
      strings str2
    where  
      str2.id <> str1.id
      and str2.string like str1.string || '%'
)
```